# How to display the countdown time for all users

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I am building a flutter auction application, I am stuck at the countdown time of an auction product so I use firebase realtime database.
I have to make sure all users see the countdown at the same time.
Please help me whether it's just a keyword to search for, a similar example or something that can help me.
And I can use nodejs to assist,

[image]

This is my database,
I want when a user posts a product of theirs, the time countdown, and I get that data to display it on the screen.
Where do I put that countdown timer? In flutter or firebase. I'm crying.
Thank you for everything,

Comment: can you share ui that will clear idea to community to answer your question well

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to set the ending `DateTime` of your auction. For example, if you want your auction to be terminated after two hours, you can add

```
endingTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 2))
```

to Firebase realtime database, and then when users come to your auction, you can just use a `Timer.periodic` to calculate the remaining time for every 1 second, and stop the timer when the current `DateTime` exceeds the termination time:

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
  remainingTime = endingTime.difference(DateTime.now());
  if (remainingTime <= Duration.zero) {
     timer.cancel()
  }
});
```

And finally, you can just use `setState` to render `remainingTime`, or implement `StreamController` with `StreamBuilder` to render it. Hope it helps.